# parse name from user input when using jquery serialize

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to grab user input from a dynamic form using jquery serialize. My form looks like this

```
        <form id="lookUpForm">
            <input name="q" id="websterInput"  />
            <button onclick="webster(); return false;">Search</button>
        </form>
```

I want to take the input, and attach it to the end of websters dictionary URL to search for a word. 
http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ + (user input)

When you run an alert to see what the value of 'q' is, you get

q=input

so for example if I put 'cats'

the alert would say q=cats.

I want the the string to just be what the user entered. However, you need to give the input a name to use seralize. So how can I take the user input, and strip out the 'q=' part.

EDIT

as requested here is the function I'm calling. Note. I HAVE to use serialize(); This isnt an option.

```
function webster() {
    var stringHolder = $("#lookUpForm").serialize();
    alert(stringHolder);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        crossDomain: 'true',
        url: "http://www.merriam-webster.com/" + stringHolder,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            console.log("http://www.merriam-webster.com/" + stringHolder);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Failed to get dictionary data");
            console.log("http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/" + stringHolder);
        }

    });


};
```

Comment: If you only have one param you could just replace the `q=` or is it possible that you have more than one param?

Comment: Its possible to have more than one parameter which is why I need to use serialize.

Comment: ok, could you add your `webster` function to your question?

Comment: couldn't you just do a `$('#websterInput').val()` separate from the serialization?

Comment: have a look at my answer, that should solve your problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `serializeArray()`.

And then do something like this and put your string together like you want to

```
var array = $("#lookUpForm").serializeArray();

$(array ).each(function(){
   alert(this.value); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just access it using `val` method of jQuery

```
function webster() {
    var stringHolder = $("#lookUpForm").serialize();
    alert(stringHolder);
    $.ajax({
        // (...) removed some code for brevity
        error: function () {
            alert("Failed to get dictionary data");
            console.log("http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/" + 
            $('#websterInput').val()); // I suppose you want the user-input here
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Because I need to use serialize to grab the info from the form.

Comment: @onTheInternet please show your current code as it isn't quite clear

Comment: sorry. Added function.